# USB doesn't work under Windows 7 and MSI B450M

Tags: windows-7, usb, motherboard, windows-update, windows-installer

I am unable to operate normal on Windows 7 and MSI B450M motherboard, because:

1) Neither USB device working, including keyboard and mouse

2) Windows update doesn't help, because it says processor is incompatible (AMD Ryzen 2400G)

3) I can't run motherboard acompanying setup CD but unknown reason. First I thought this is because it's GUI can't work mousless, but later I activated keyboard mouse manipulation but still unable to click "Install" button. During load it says KB3033929 not found. I can't install this KB because it says "Unknown error"

Is it possible to install USB drivers separately?

Please don't suggest to install Windows 10, it is not an option.

Comment: If this just happened on a working setup, I would suspect a hardware problem rather than a sudden software problem. That is, unless you installed lately some badly-behaved product or driver.

Comment: Do you have USB Legacy Mode enable or disabled?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  `KB3033929`, is a patch that was released 4+ years ago, did you already have it installed or something?